# Domain validates but won't save

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have the following setup.

Class, say, Car that has a CarPart (belongsTo=[car:Car]).

When I'm creating a Car I also want to create som default CarParts, so I do

```
def car = new Car(bla bla bla)
def part = new CarPart(car:car)
```

Now, when I do car.validate() or part.validate() it seems fine.
But when I do if(car.save && part.save() I get this exception:

```
    2012-03-24 14:02:21,943 [http-8080-4] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Batch entry 0 insert into car_part (version, car_id, id) values ('0', '297', '298') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
2012-03-24 14:02:21,943 [http-8080-4] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ERROR: value too long for type character varying(6)
2012-03-24 14:02:21,943 [http-8080-4] ERROR events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into car_part (version, deal_id, id) values ('0', '297', '298') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2621)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1837)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:407)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2754)
    at $Proxy20.flush(Unknown Source)
    at ristretto.DealController$_closure5.doCall(DealController.groovy:109)
    at ristretto.DealController$_closure5.doCall(DealController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling validate is really only going to check constraints.  What is failing on your save is the actual persistance to the database (validate can't really check that).

Generally, in Grails, you would want to do this 1 of 2 ways:

```
def car = new Car(bla bla)
car.save()
def carPart = new CarPart(car:car)
carPart.save()
```

or

```
def car = new Car(bla bla)
def carPart = new CarPart(bla bla)
car.addToCarParts(carPart)
car.save()
```

Comment: Good answer, BUT what I really want to do this with some type of transaction, if for some reason the CarPart doesn't save neither should the Car...

Comment: So put it in a service and the transaction will be handled.  If that case, my second example is going to be better.  If CarPart fails, the error will persist up to Car and the transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: I tried doing it in a service now, I get my car (that's already created) and do CarPart p = new CarPart(bla bla bla).save(), it gives me: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into car_part (version, created, car_id, status, id) values ('0', '2012-03-26 23:11:01.512000 +02:00:00', '303', 'SHAFT', '368') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2621)

Comment: Ok in the end it turns out I needed to do a carPart.refresh()!